# Howto Verify Signature of a SMIME multipart/signed application/x-pkcs7-signature Mail

Tags: c#, smime, openpop

I am working on a larger application which receives email by POP3, IMAP or through import from .msg Files (Exported form Outlook or dragged over from Outlook).

Recently I received an email with an attachment "smime.p7m".
After further inspection it turned out to be a MIME Message with

> Content-Type: multipart/signed;
>   protocol="application/x-pkcs7-signature";

Among other parts it contains one section

> Content-Type: application/x-pkcs7-signature; name="smime.p7s"
>   Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 Content-Disposition: attachment;
>   filename="smime.p7s"

I tried to verify this signature using `OpenPop` as a MIME Message Parser and `SignedCms` to check the signature. My attempt looks like this:

```
var datapart = OpenPop.MessagePart[...];
var part3 = OpenPop.MessagePart[3]; // the signature

var ci = new ContentInfo(datapart);            
var sCMS = new SignedCms(ci, detached: true);
sCMS.Decode(part3.Body);
sCMS.CheckHash();

sCMS.CheckSignature(verifySignatureOnly:true);
```

But no matter what I use for `datapart` I always get

> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException 
>   The hash value is not correct.

How can I verify the signature?

Are there better approaches?

Comment: Did my answer help at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way for you to do this would be to use [MimeKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit) (which is not only open source but also free for commercial use).

Since all you care about is verifying the signatures, you could just use a `MimeKit.Cryptography.TemporarySecureMimeContext` instead of setting up your own (like the README and other documentation talks about doing).

Typically, when you receive a message signed via S/MIME, it is almost always the root-level MIME part that is the `multipart/signed` part, which makes this somewhat easier (the first step toward verifying signatures is to locate the `multipart/signed` part).

```
var signed = message.Body as MultipartSigned;
if (signed != null) {
    using (var ctx = new TemporaryMimeContext ()) {
        foreach (var signature in signed.Verify (ctx)) {
            try {
                bool valid = signature.Verify ();

                // If valid is true, then it signifies that the signed
                // content has not been modified since this particular
                // signer signed the content.
                //
                // However, if it is false, then it indicates that the
                // signed content has
                // been modified.
            } catch (DigitalSignatureVerifyException) {
                // There was an error verifying the signature.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can find API documentation for MimeKit at [www.mimekit.net/docs](http://www.mimekit.net/docs).